# Issue while placing Bar Button on Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard, uibarbuttonitem

## I want

to add a bar button on top right of my navigation bar.

## I drag

and drop the bar button from UI Library into my navigation bar. It places my bar button in the bottom of the view instead.

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drag a navigation item onto your view controller first (also from the library). *Then* you can add the bar button item by dragging it into the navigation item.

[image: navigation item]